# Ways to programmatically determine the likely sharpness of a digital photograph?

Tags: image-processing, automation, imagemagick

I'd like to automate checking for the sharpness of a large collection of digital images.  It doesn't have to be perfect, but if it can tell a sharp from a blurry photograph > 70% of the time, it would be a lifesaver.

Are there any libraries, methods, or software packages that can do this?

Comment: I have a site that hosts a large number of images.  Most everything is automated.  I want to start selling poster-sized prints of the larger images without having to curate them.  If possible, I'd like to stop blurry, out of focus images that won't look good in a large print format from being ordered in the first place, display a warning, or otherwise make sure the purchaser is fully informed.

Comment: The images are basically outdoors photographs of nature, inside pets, or similar.  A little schmalzy but no other consistent theme.  The ones I'd be interested in analyzing would have at least one edge > 1200 pixels.  I have a few ideas for dealing with the possible blurry photos (showing cropped sections at 100% for the buyer to examine) but I'd rather not worry the purchaser unless there's a good chance there's an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you are just looking at the ratio of high frequencies to low.
But you would need to decide on some level which corresponded to 'in focus' for different images - it's a bit tricky on scenes of smooth sand dunes!

A quick and dirty version might be to take a line accross the image and look at the average difference between pixels a few pixels apart - big difference = high contrast = focused

Most algorithms are looking at a series of images (for autofocus) and so you only need to worry about finding a maxima.

Comment: The problem with this is, say the image is primarily of someone's pet (as the OP suggested could be the case in the comments), then if the area around the pet is *even slightly blurry* it's going to look bad for the customer. But the image as a whole might have nice sharp boundaries everywhere else. Localized blur detection is really hard, and the single-image deconvolution problem is *extremely* hard.

Comment: If most of the images are of open, generic scenes without much specific content in the foreground, then you could just apply a sharpening filter a few times, see if there's a large-norm difference between the sharpened version and the original, and if not, declare it to already be sharp. Localized blur analogs of this are really difficult to get working in practice.

Comment: The sharpen-and-compare approach sounds interesting.  Do you have experience that it works?